# sql server:Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

I create a table with fields below in sql server 2016

```
[ID] int primary key not null,[FirstName] nvarchar(50),[LastName] nvarchar(50),[Gender] nvarchar(10),[Salary] int,[DepartmentId] int
```

I forgot to make ID as entity so I drop it and made a new field with the name new_id as identity(1,1)

now when I insert some rows I get the following error:
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I choose database from the top and then make a query with this instructions:

```
insert into Employees values ('Mark','Hastings','Male',60000,1)
insert into Employees values ('Steve','Pound','Male',45000,3)
insert into Employees values ('Ben','Hoskins','Male',70000,1)
insert into Employees values ('Philip','Hastings','Male',45000,2)
insert into Employees values ('Mary','Lambeth','female',30000,2)
insert into Employees values ('Valaries','Vikings','Female',35000,3)
insert into Employees values ('John','Stanmore','Male',80000,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you forgot to make the ID column with Identity.

Change your ID column to auto generate values with Identity property

```
[ID] int Identity primary key not null,[FirstName] nvarchar(50).........
```

Your table definition should be like

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEESS (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    ,[FirstName] NVARCHAR(50)
    ,[LastName] NVARCHAR(50)
    ,[Gender] NVARCHAR(10)
    ,[Salary] INT
    ,[DepartmentId] INT
    )
```

So that ID column will auto generated the values. And it is always advisable to List the column names while inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
insert into Employees([FirstName],[LastName],[Gender],[Salary],[DepartmentId]) values ('Mark','Hastings','Male',60000,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns to insert on, which would avoid the ambiguity.

```
INSERT INTO Employees([FirstName],[LastName],[Gender],[Salary],[DepartmentId])
VALUES ('Mark','Hastings','Male',60000,1)
```

or, another way to insert

```
INSERT INTO Employees([FirstName],[LastName],[Gender],[Salary],[DepartmentId])
SELECT 'Mark','Hastings','Male',60000,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Steve','Pound','Male',45000,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ben','Hoskins','Male',70000,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Philip','Hastings','Male',45000,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mary','Lambeth','female',30000,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'Valaries','Vikings','Female',35000,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'John','Stanmore','Male',80000,1
```

Comment: ID column is imposed with Primary key. So it wont allow nulls. Your insert will fail

Comment: @ShakeerMirza He said it was dropped in the original question: "I forgot to make ID as entity so I drop it and made a new field with the name new_id as identity(1,1)"

Answer (score 0):

You should include the field names you are assigning :

```
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('Mark','Hastings','Male',60000,1)
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('Steve','Pound','Male',45000,3)
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('Ben','Hoskins','Male',70000,1)
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('Philip','Hastings','Male',45000,2)
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('Mary','Lambeth','female',30000,2)
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('Valaries','Vikings','Female',35000,3)
insert into Employees ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], [Salary] ,[DepartmentId]) values ('John','Stanmore','Male',80000,1)
```

Comment: ID column is imposed with Primary key. So it wont allow nulls. Your insert will fail

Comment: Doesn't he say he has dropped ID and added an identity field NEW_ID ? (the identity field will be populated automatically).

Comment: In his question he mentioned the schema. If it is not an identity column, we can't insert with specifying columns also. Because the ID column having `Primary key`

Comment: Yes, but he also says he has dropped the ID column and replaced it by a NEW_ID identity column.